# design database table structure

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-structures, data-modeling

I'm writing application using relational database. I have entity of **document** that have to be persist in the database. The document is simply large table with many rows and columns:

[image: Structure of document]

But problem is that many of the rows and columns may vary depending on the situation. Each document can have its own set of rows and columns. Even number of rows and columns can change. 
Therefore, I can't only create single table `DOCUMENT` in database. In that case I would have to constantly change the structure of the table using [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language).

I need to come up with flexible and adaptable database structure. So that an user has only right to data manipulation ([CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)-operations) could use this db scheme.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind is the following: You create one table for the attributes, that every `document` has. Like a name, a creation date or whatever.

And for all things that may vary, you create antoher table, in which you insert the data, that is really there. Like so:

```
document_id paramater_name string_value    int_value date_value
----------- -------------- --------------- --------- -----------
      1987         comment     "cool doc."
      1987        due_date                            12/24/2014
     20124        old_name         abc.txt
     20124            cost                      1.99
```

But be sure, this is a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

What is *in* the documents? What is their nature?

Do you need to sort/filter/count/etc on the individual attributes?

You could store the documents in one text field and use Full-Text Search to search them.

Or you could store in them in Solr/Lucene.